# how to avoid over lapping legends and pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, pie-chart

I am trying to draw a pie chart using python `matplotlib`. How to position the legend and pie chart so they are not overlapping each other. My code is as below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
y = np.array([1,117,11,5])
mylabels ="Complete","Pass","Fail","Block"
mycolors = ["b","g","r","c"]
myexplode =[0.6,0,0.4,0]
plt.pie(y,labels=mylabels,explode = myexplode,shadow=True,colors = mycolors,autopct 
='%1.1f%%')
plt.legend(title ="Test result types")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bbox_to_anchor` parameter in `plt.legend`

```
plt.legend(title="Test result types", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.15))
```

[image]